# using images as radio buttons using css and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use one single image sprite for typical male / female radio buttons but its simply showing nothing and i'm struggling to understand why:

jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('input:radio').each(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $('<a class="radio-fx" href="#"><div class="radio"></div></a>').insertAfter(this);
});
$('.radio-fx').live('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
      var $check = $(this).prev('input');
      $('.radio-fx div').attr('class','radio');
      $(this).find('div').attr('class','radio-checked');          
      $check.attr('checked', true);
});
});
</script>
```

The CSS I'm trying:

```
    #male .radio {
    background: url(/images_/icons/mf_radio.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    width: 57px;
    height: 63px;
}

#male .radio:hover {
    background-position: 0 -62px;
}

#male .radio-checked {
    background: url(/images_/icons/mf_radio.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 -124px;
    width: 57px;
    height: 63px;
}

#female .radio{
    background: url(/images_/icons/mf_radio.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: -57px 0px;
    width: 57px;
    height: 63px;
}

#female .radio:hover {
    background-position: -57px -62px;
}

#female .radio-checked {
    background: url(/images_/icons/mf_radio.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: -57px -124px;
    width: 57px;
    height: 63px;
}
```

Finally, the html:

```
<input type="radio" class="radio" id="female" value="Female" />
<input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="Male" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It displays nothing because you are hiding the radio buttons using with `$(this).hide()`, then adding some anchor tags **after** the radio buttons with the class `.radio-fx` and a child div with the class `.radio`.

Your CSS references elements nested within an id (such as `#male .radio`) and not after. So there is nothing that references the `.radio-fx .radio` element in your CSS and the elements themselves contain no visual content - therefore you see nothing.

For a quick CSS fix you could change your selectors to `#id + * > .class`, for example `#male .radio` would become `#male + * > .radio`.

You might also want to add `a.radio-fix{ display: block; }` since you are nesting a `div` within an anchor tag.

On an additional note, you should probably consider adding some text to your anchor tags as I believe screen readers will see it as an empty anchor tag (how you see it now with no visible content).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that in your javascript you hide the input elements with the #male/#female IDs and in your CSS you use them as selectors to style your graphic radio buttons. Remove the #male/#female from the CSS or add them to the HTML you create with your javascript. It's hard to say which is best as we can't see the image you're using and therefore exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Here's a quick fiddle for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/7XEnc/9/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify `-webkit-appearance: none` for your overrides to take effect on Webkit browsers.